# Trying to modify a variable inside of a class

Tags: c++, class

Hey so I'm trying to modify the variable counter but it keeps outputting zero after i try to set it. What am i doing wrong? How to i modify the variable counter so that it will be updated by the increase function. The program is supposed to be able to count up and down while also starting at a user specified location

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class CounterType
{
public:

    void increase();
    void decrease();
    void display();
    void setting(int newNumber);
    void CurrentDisplay();
    int counter;

};

int main()
{
    CounterType counter;
    int x;
    int whichCase;
    cout << "Please enter a number to start counting at" << endl;
    cin >> x;
    counter.setting(x);
    int Continue = 1;
    counter.CurrentDisplay();
    while (Continue == 1)
    {

        cout << "Push 1: Increase" << endl;
        cout << "Push 2: Decrease" << endl;
        cout << "Push 3: Display" << endl;
        cin >> whichCase;
        while (whichCase > 3 || cin.fail() || whichCase < 1)
        {
            cout << "No such case exists you dummy" << endl;
            cout << "Please enter a valid number" << endl;
            cin >> whichCase;
        }
        switch (whichCase)
        {
            case 1:
                counter.increase();
            case 2:
                counter.decrease();
            case 3:
                counter.display();
        }
        cout << "Would you like to continue? 1 for yes 2 for no" << endl;
        cin >> Continue;
        while (Continue > 2 || Continue < 1 || cin.fail())
        {
            cout << "Please enter a valid number: " << endl;
            cin >> Continue;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void CounterType::setting(int newNumber)
{

    if (newNumber >= 0)
        counter = newNumber;
    if (newNumber < 0)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a valid number. Program exited" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
}

void CounterType::increase()
{
    counter = counter + 1;
}
void CounterType::decrease()
{
    if (counter = 0)
    {
        cout << "Cannot decrease any further" << endl;
        counter = 0;
    }
    if (counter > 0)
    {
        counter = counter - 1;
    }
}
void CounterType::display()
{
    cout << "Counter is " << counter << endl;
    ;
}
void CounterType::CurrentDisplay()
{
    cout << "Counter is " << counter << endl;
}
```

Comment: You forgot your `break`s in `switch(whichCase)`. Every time you increase you also immediately decrease.

Comment: Improve your code formatting please, that's too hard to read! Also please remove all that irrelevant code and provide a [MCVE].

Comment: If you are using an input loop using `cin.fail()` you should `cin.clear()` when it fails. Otherwise it will just stay failed forever.

Comment: Most modern compilers will warn you that `if (counter = 0)` isn't kosher. Do not ignore warning messages as they mean while the code compiles, it probably doesn't do what you would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
if (counter = 0)
```

sets `counter` to `0` and then tests it for nonzero.
What you want to do is probably :

```
if (counter == 0)
```

Also, your switch statement is missing `break` statements.  Replace

```
switch(whichCase)
{
case 1:
    counter.increase();
case 2:
    counter.decrease();
case 3:
    counter.display();
}
```

with

```
switch (whichCase)
{
    case 1:
        counter.increase();
        break;
    case 2:
        counter.decrease();
        break;
    case 3:
        counter.display();
}
```

And, you should initialize the counter, e.g. like this:

```
CounterType counter{ 0 };
```

Or better yet, create a constructor for `CounterType` and initialize the `counter` member variable there.